# How to combine multiple unordered rows into a single row with pandas [CSV file]

Tags: python

I have data in the following format in csv file

> 1) Pedestrian; - ; - ; - ; - ; 5.74; 0.018771; 2080.04; 522.40;
>   0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000;
>   2080.04; 522.40; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 41.7083; 2080.04; 522.40; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 83.4167
>
> ; 2080.04; 522.40; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 125.1250; 2080.04; 522.40;
>   0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000;
>   166.8333;
>
> 2) Pedestrian; - ; - ; - ; - ; 5.74; 0.018771;2104.25; 528.51; 0.0671;
>   -0.3212; -0.1091; 178595.0833; 2104.30;
>
> 528.53; 0.0566; -0.3056; -0.1113; 178636.7917; 2104.34; 528.56; 0.0466; -0.2926; -0.1125; 178678.5000    ; 2104.39; 528.58; 0.0375; -0.2613; -0.1128; 178720.2083; 2104.44; 528.61; 0.0299; -0.2221; -0.1116;
>
> 78761.9167; 2104.48; 528.63; 0.0235; -0.0841; -0.1063; 178803.625;

This csv file don't have header and also, each row don't have same order. For example, some row ends with semicolon(;) but some rows end with numbers and some rows started with semicolon. I want to change the format like this:

```
1; Pedestrian; - ; - ; - ; - ; 5.74; 0.018771; ----------------------------------------------

2; Pedestrian; - ; - ; - ; - ; 5.74; 0.018771;-----------------------------------------------
```

Is there any elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

This might help. You can use the `csv module` to read your file.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
s = "PATH_TO.csv"

res = []
with open(s, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for line in reader:
        if line:
            if ")" in line[0]:
                print "; ".join(line[:7]), "-"*46
```

**Output:**

```
1) Pedestrian;  - ;  - ;  - ;  - ;  5.74;  0.018771; ----------------------------------------------
2) Pedestrian;  - ;  - ;  - ;  - ;  5.74;  0.018771; ----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh,

But I need the output like following:

1) Pedestrian;  - ;  - ;  - ;  - ;  5.74;  0.018771;--------------; 0.0000; 166.8333; 
2) Pedestrian;  - ;  - ;  - ;  - ;  5.74;  0.018771;--------------; -0.1063; 178803.625;

Is there is any solution for this?

Comment: Just add the required amount of "-" to the print Ex: ......print "; ".join(line[:7]), "-------------------"

Comment: print all the values of pedestrian 1 in one row, and pedestrian 2 in another row. for example 

1) Pedestrian; - ; - ; - ; - ; 5.74; 0.018771; 2080.04; 522.40; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 2080.04; 522.40; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 41.7083; 2080.04; 522.40; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 83.4167

; 2080.04; 522.40; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 125.1250; 2080.04; 522.40; 0.0000; 0.0000; 0.0000; 166.8333;

The above all the values aligned in to single row.

Comment: Please check each row don't have same order. For example, some row ends with semicolon(;) but some rows end with numbers and some rows started with semicolon.